# How do I stop a process running using Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, process

I want to write a Perl code that ends the process of another program of mine, running on Linux.

For example, I execute `xxy.py` and a process is opened for it. I would like to use Perl to close the process of `xxy.py`. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl extensions are typically .pl or .pm right?  .py is for python I think.

Anyway, you can kill a specified program in a Unix environment with something like:

```
system 'killall', 'some_program_name';
```

or

```
system 'kill', '-15', $pid;
```

if the variable $pid holds the pid of your program.

Comment: A better way to write that is `system 'kill', '-9', $pid;`. That will avoid going through a shell

Comment: Additionally, you should probably avoid using `-9` (`SIGKILL`) as it doesn't give the process you're killing any chance to clean itself up. `SIGTERM` (usually `-15`) is better.

Comment: You're right.  I will edit my post to reflect this.  I was just used to having to kill unresponsive programs with 9.

Comment: perl has a kill builtin; use it instead of an external program...

Answer (score 1):

use killall to kill processes by process names. if you *have to* use perl. do a system call from within there.

Comment: could anyone explain the negatives here?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but perhaps it's because only the FreeBSD-style `killall` cares about the name given.  SysV-style `killall` is much more literal and will attempt to kill **all** processes. (Or, given that this is SO, they could just be random drive-by downvotes...)

Comment: thanks Dave. you figure right. i come from a freebsd background. din't know killall doesnt work the same. would definitely try killall if i get to a linux system. sounds a crazy function.

the good news is that someone had sympathy to my downvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

See [`kill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) and [`pkill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) manual pages.